# How to test a factory that has a method that returns a promise in Karma / Mocha?

Tags: unit-testing, promise, mocha.js, karma-runner, angular-mock

I am new to unit testing angular code, and have been trying to figure this out.  I am using Karma, Mocha and Chai.  Asynchronous unit testing is [supported](http://visionmedia.github.io/mocha/) in Mocha (Asynchronous code) via a mechanism that looks like this:

```
describe('User', function(){
  describe('#save()', function(){
    it('should save without error', function(done){
      var user = new User('Luna');
      user.save(done);
    })
  })
})
```

which I assume can be rewritten assuming savePromise is a promise implementation

```
describe('User', function(){
  describe('#save()', function(){
    it('should save without error', function(done){
      var user = new User('Luna');
      user.savePromise().then(function(){
        done()
      })
    })
  })
})
```

that would be cool, but inject from angular-mock doesn't push the done function into the "it" callback.  I reviewed the code and even tried it (knowing it would fail).  Essentially I believe I  want something like this

```
describe('#save()', function(){
   it('should save without error', inject(function (User, done) {

      var user = new User('Luna');
      user.savePromise().then(function(){
        done()
      })
   }) 
})
```

How do I get angular-mock to work with Mocha?

Answer (score 0):

Wait... is it as simple as performing your injections and before the test?

```
var myUser
beforeEach(inject(function (User) {
    myUser = User
}))

describe('#save()', function(){
   it('should save without error', function (done) {

      var user = new myUser('Luna');
      user.savePromise().then(function(){
        done()
      })
   }) 
})
```

It still is not working in my case.  I am trying to test a HTTP client which doesn't look to be making the calls.  However the code looks like, if I make the change above, that it should work.